# access VBA how to remove duplication from Collection

Tags: ms-access, collections, vba, time-complexity

how do I remove duplication of objects in a Collection? This is what I tried:

```
    dim unique_students as Collection
    dim no_duplicate_student as cls_Student
    dim no_duplication as boolean

For Each student as cls_Student In list_Student 'list_Students = original unsorted collection

         no_duplication = True

         Dim s As cls_Student
         For Each s In unique_students

            If s.name = student.name  Then 
               no_duplication = False 'Duplication found
               Exit For
            End If

         next s

         If no_duplication Then 
'Inserted into new sorted collection if no values matches that of the sorted collection

           Set no_duplicate_student = New clsOverlap
           no_duplicate_student.name = student.name

           unique_students.Add no_duplicate_student

         End If

Next student
```

This however still takes a long time (`if list_Student.Count > 5000`, then it'll take 30min+ to run). Is there a more efficient way (if possible, decrease time complexity) of removing duplication in a Collection?

Comment: Doesn't the collection origin from a table? If so, it should be much faster simply to adjust the query retrieving the data.

Answer (score 1):

Add the student names to a **dictionary**, which has the `.Exists` method to check if an item is already in the dictionary.

You can get some ideas from `CollectionToDictionary` in [Collection And Dictionary Procedures](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm)

Something like this in your `For Each student` loop:

```
If Dict.Exists(Key:=student.name) Then
    ' is duplicate!
Else
    Dict.Add Key:=student.name, Item:=student.name
    ' you could also do Item:=student if you want the de-duplicated list in a dictionary
End If
```

The inner loop is not needed. The function will probably run almost instantaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a dictionary like what Andre451 suggested. Alternatively you could use an ArrayList like this. I'm not sure if there's much of a performance difference between the two but this method also produces a sorted list if that's desirable. The dictionary though can carry key/value pairs, so it just depends on what you're going after.

```
Sub Demo()
    Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    AL.Add "A"
    AL.Add "B"
    AL.Add "A"
    AL.Add "A"
    AL.Add "C"
    'Sorting allows sequential comparisons to determine uniqueness
    'You could also do something similar to the dictionary method with ArrayList.Contains 
    'but the evluation of ArrayList.Contains runs slower than this
    AL.Sort
    For i = 0 To AL.Count - 2
        If AL(i) <> AL(i + 1) Then
           'Prints unique values
            Debug.Print AL(i)
        End If
    Next
    If AL(i) <> AL(i - 1) Then
        'Prints last value if unique by comparing to one before it
        Debug.Print AL(i)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:** After testing I confirmed that the dictionary method is about twice as fast at 7.7 seconds versus 13 seconds per million. However, at the OP count of 5000 the difference is only 40 vs 80 ms.

Testing Code Here...

```
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long
Sub DictionaryDemo()
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For i = 0 To 10 ^ 6
        AL.Add Round(Rnd * 10, 0)
    Next

    Start = GetTickCount
    For i = 0 To AL.Count - 1
        If Not (D.Exists(AL(i))) Then
            D.Add AL(i), ""
            Debug.Print AL(i)
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print GetTickCount - Start
End Sub
Sub ArrayListDemo()
    Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For i = 0 To 10 ^ 6
        AL.Add Round(Rnd * 10, 0)
    Next

    'Sorting allows sequential comparisons to determine uniqueness
    Start = GetTickCount
    AL.Sort
    For i = 0 To AL.Count - 2
        If AL(i) <> AL(i + 1) Then
           'Prints unique values
            Debug.Print AL(i)
        End If
    Next
    If AL(i) <> AL(i - 1) Then
        'Prints last value if unique by comparing to one before it
        Debug.Print AL(i)
    End If
    Debug.Print GetTickCount - Start
End Sub
```

**Edit Again:** Ok, so I find this very interesting. What's most important appears to be the actual type itself. So for example, the testing above creates an ArrayList from which unique values are to be derived. If this is changed to a basic integer array `Dim AL(10 ^ 6) As Integer`, then the time is slashed from 7.7 to 0.8 seconds. Likewise, the ArrayList method can be slashed from 13 seconds down to 0.5 seconds simply by adding the line `A = AL.ToArray` after the sorting operation and looping through the array `A` instead.

This makes sense, since the memory allocation for arrays allows them to be processed really quick. It's also why some people prefer to create their own sorting and uniqueness algorithms rather than go with a less efficient but easy to use method employing a Dictionary or ArrayList as originally suggested here. The dictionary and ArrayLists are still powerful tools and, as mentioned above, they can still extract unique values from a 1 million length in a fraction of a second, but it's worth noting that when it comes to raw efficiency a simple array is wicked fast at looping.

The code below will extract unique values from a 1 million length array in about 0.3 seconds. It's not much different than the OP, but it's a lot more efficient.  This is because looping through a collection is horribly slow, not because there was anything inefficient with the basic strategy. Also, notice that the efficiency will decrease as the number of unique values increases (this test only used the 10 unique of 1-10).

```
Sub ArrayDemo()
    Dim A(10 ^ 6) As Integer
    Dim B(10) As Integer
    For i = 0 To 10 ^ 6
        A(i) = Round(Rnd * 10, 0)
    Next

    Start = GetTickCount
    k = 0
    For i = 0 To 10 ^ 6
        For j = 0 To k
            If B(j) = A(i) Then GoTo nxt
        Next
        B(k) = A(i)
        Debug.Print B(k)
        k = k + 1  
nxt:
    Next
    Debug.Print GetTickCount - Start
End Sub
```

Comment: So the best way would be to sort first, then remove any duplications after that.

Comment: @KennyNguyen No, not necessarily the best, just another way. The main point is that for this kind of stuff ArrayLists and Dictionaries are more powerful than Collections, but they each have their own pros and cons as well. ArrayLists don't enforce uniqueness, so sorting is a good way to process them for unique values. Dictionaries do enforce key uniqueness, which makes them more efficiency at verifying it. Dictionaries are not good at sorting though, but they are good at associating data. So it all just depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @KennyNguyen as my second edit points out. Even though ArrayLists and Dictionaries are very powerful tools in their own right, when it comes to efficiency, looping through a simple array is the fastest. I'm not sure if you can make that suite your needs in this case or not.